# RottenTomatoes API can't render synopsis

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working with the RottenTomatoes movies API. I have the following code, but I can't seem to print out the movie's synopsis to the screen beneath the input. Any idea om what I'm doing wrong here?

See AJAX call example here: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs

```
<formx>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Movie name" name="search">
</form>
<div id="search_results">

</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 3,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?callback=?", {
                    apikey: "api_key_here",
                    q: request.term,
                    page_limit: 10
                }, function(data) {
                    // data is an array of objects and must be transformed for autocomplete to use
                    var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data.movies, function(m) {
                        return {
                            label: m.title + " (" + m.year + ")",
                            url: m.links.alternate,
                            synopsis: m.synopsis
                        };
                    });
                    response(array);
                });
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();

                document.write(ui.synopsis);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();

                document.write(ui.synopsis);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provite an output example from the API.

Comment: Sorry, right here: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs

Comment: If you could paste the example where it fails would be nice. Also, edit your question with this data, just to make sure everyone who reads the question sees it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the usage of `document.write()` here is unintended, you'll want to write specifically to that targeted `DIV`

Comment: Well, it simply returns nothing when I'm selecting, and I've written in the code under select that it should write the synopsis to the page, nothing happens, white/blank screen.

Comment: I've already tried writing: `$("#movie").html(ui.synopsis);` also added the div with the ID and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using the sample API response from the RT dev site, do you have a better example of the JSON response that I can use for a JSFiddle demo?

Comment: Maybe this one http://pastebin.com/gwh37pnU

Comment: I got it to work, weird because it was a solution I've tried multiple times.`

`ui.item.field_here` returned the field I was looking for, and I simply used the html() function within jQuery to display the content.

Comment: I've got it to work as well, will post an updated JSFiddle as an answer unless you want to close this question out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52704/discussion-between-ishan-chatterjee-and-dueify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work with the exception of the `ui.synopsis` object calls. The jQueryUI `ui` object that is passed in actually doesn't refer to the result array item directly. Rather you have to use `ui.item` to access the original result item:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 3,
    source: processed,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#search_results').text(ui.item.synopsis);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

In the above example, I've removed the `AJAX` call completely and used the hard-coded response that you had supplied earlier. However the data manipulation/setup is still following the same logic as what you have above.

**FIDDLE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Sta5N/**